# MySQL - Conflicting WHERE and GROUP BY Statements

Tags: mysql

I have a query returning the counts of some data, but I do NOT want data that has a null value in it...

As an example, the code rolls stats from a clicking system into a table.

```
SELECT sh.dropid,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(sh2.`SentDate` IS NOT NULL, sh2.`subid`, NULL)) AS sentCount,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(sh2.`Open` = 1, sh2.`subid`, NULL)) AS openCount,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(sh2.`Click` = 1, sh2.`subhistid`, NULL)) AS clickCount,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(sh2.`Bounced` = 1, sh2.`subid`, NULL)) AS bounceCount,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(sh2.`Unsubscribed` = 1, sh2.`subid`, NULL)) AS unsubCount,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(sh2.`Abuse` = 1, sh2.`subid`, NULL)) AS abuseCount
FROM subscriberhistory sh
INNER JOIN subscriberhistory sh2 ON sh.subid = sh2.subid
WHERE sh.SentDate >= '#runDate# #lastRunTime#'
AND sh.dropid IS NOT NULL
AND sh.dropid != ""
OR (sh.SentDate IS NULL AND sh.OpenDate >= '#runDate# #lastRunTime#')
OR (sh.SentDate IS NULL AND sh.ClickDate >= '#runDate# #lastRunTime#')
OR (sh.SentDate IS NULL AND sh.UnsubscribeDate >= '#runDate# #lastRunTime#')
OR (sh.SentDate IS NULL AND sh.BouncedDate >= '#runDate# #lastRunTime#')
OR (sh.SentDate IS NULL AND sh.AbuseDate >= '#runDate# #lastRunTime#')
GROUP BY dropid
ORDER BY sentCount DESC
```

EDIT: Corrected query

```
SELECT sh.dropid,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(sh2.`SentDate` IS NOT NULL, sh2.`subid`, NULL)) AS sentCount,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(sh2.`Open` = 1, sh2.`subid`, NULL)) AS openCount,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(sh2.`Click` = 1, sh2.`subid`, NULL)) AS clickCount,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(sh2.`Bounced` = 1, sh2.`subid`, NULL)) AS bounceCount,  
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(sh2.`Unsubscribed` = 1, sh2.`subid`, NULL)) AS unsubCount,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(sh2.`Abuse` = 1, sh2.`subid`, NULL)) AS abuseCount
FROM subscriberhistory sh
INNER JOIN subscriberhistory sh2 ON sh.subid = sh2.subid
WHERE sh.dropid IS NOT NULL AND sh.dropid != ""
AND ((sh.SentDate >= '2012-04-10 14:15') 
OR (sh.SentDate IS NULL AND sh.OpenDate >= '2012-04-10 14:15')
OR (sh.SentDate IS NULL AND sh.ClickDate >= '2012-04-10 14:15')
OR (sh.SentDate IS NULL AND sh.UnsubscribeDate >= '2012-04-10 14:15')
OR (sh.SentDate IS NULL AND sh.BouncedDate >= '2012-04-10 14:15')
OR (sh.SentDate IS NULL AND sh.AbuseDate >= '2012-04-10 14:15'))
GROUP BY sh.dropid
ORDER BY sentCount DESC
```

An example of the record set returned would look like this...

```
(dropid) sent opens  clicks
400      2    3      4
401      2    3      6
NULL     2    3      4
```

Again, the goal is to keep the NULL data out of the preceding record set. Could someone explain to me why this behavior is occurring and what to do to solve it.

Comment: What is the purpose of the self-inner-join?  Since you join on the same column in both instances it won't do anything; also you haven't referred to `sh2` anywhere else in the query.

Comment: Ok, on your output mention the field headers

Comment: It is used in the counts. If I understand correctly, MySQL can build a table, perform manipulation on it, and return the record set in a shorter amount of time than it could performing manipulation on the real table. Be sure to tell me if I'm wrong... I also thought the join may have been causing the return of the null record, but I'm grouping and filtering on the same table, so I doubt it.

Comment: You've left out way too much information, the question is not answerable in its present form.

Comment: Edited for clarity. Anything encased in octothorpes is ColdFusion code.

Comment: My guess is that your `NULL`s are creeping in through the `OR` in your `WHERE` statement (i.e. `sh.dropid IS NOT NULL .. OR (...)` - you might need some grouping brackets.

Comment: Thank you. I've reformatted the query and it is working correctly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment - the `NULL` rows are creeping in through the `OR` condition in the `WHERE` statement.

Consider:

```
WHERE sh.dropid IS NOT NULL
AND   sh.dropid != ""
OR    ( some.other.condition )
```

Suppose you had a row with `sh.dropid` being NULL but still satisfying `some.other.condition` - then the entire `WHERE` clause would evaluate to `TRUE` because of the `OR`.

Solution - add brackets. e.g. (Depends on the logic you're after):

```
WHERE sh.dropid IS NOT NULL
  AND sh.dropid != ""
  AND (   one.condition
       OR second.condition
       OR third.condition
       )
```